# NHibernate Join Table Mapping has repeated objects

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent

I'm trying to map a relationship between three tables.

**Category**

```
CategoryId
ParentId
```

**Locale**

```
LocaleId
LocaleCode
```

**CategoryLocale**

```
ID
LocaleId
CategoryId
CategoryName
```

I also have an object with the structure

**Category**

```
CategoryId
CategoryName
ParentId
```

Here is my mapping

```
public CategoryMap()
    {

        Id(x => x.CategoryId);           
        Map(x => x.ParentId);            
        Join("CategoryLocale", m =>
        {               
            m.KeyColumn("CategoryId");
            m.Map(x => x.CategoryName);
            m.References(x => x.Locale,"LocaleId");
        });
    }
```

The query is simple

```
var query = session.QueryOver<Category>();
```

I get the right amount of categories returned, and the generated SQL is correct and returns all the possible combinations, but the mapping has duplicates, so instead of three different locales, I get the same category three times with the same locale.

Any ideas?

I had a CategoryLocale object which mapped to a category and a locale which worked when the CategoryName was placed under CategoryLocale, but I need either the Category on it's own filled out correctly, or with a Locale property in the Category object with the right value.

Comment: Shouldn't you do that join using `CategoryID` instead of `CategoryName`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual IDictionary<Locale, string> Names { get; private set; }

    public virtual string Name { get { return Names[GetActiveLocaleFromSomewhere()]; } }
}

public CategoryMap()
{
    HasMany(x => x.Names)
        .Table("CategoryLocale")
        .KeyColumn("CategoryId")
        .AsEntityMap("LocaleId")
        .Element("CategoryName")
}
```